# Admob app open ads and Banner Ads best practices

Tags: android, admob, banner-ads

I was looking for Admob app open ads and Banner Ads best practices

I found these

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZfdufLRZYU&vl=en

[https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9341964?hl=en#:~:text=Don't%20implement%20ads%20immediately,open%20ad%20frequency%20capping%20accordingly](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9341964?hl=en#:%7E:text=Don%27t%20implement%20ads%20immediately,open%20ad%20frequency%20capping%20accordingly).

how ever It says if we have banner ads its better not to show banner ads after the app open ad is shown

My questions are

1. is it possible to hide banner ad onresume
2. should we show a splash screen in between like after the app open ad is closed and the activity(say there are  main activity/second activity like user is on second activity now app is in background for some reason then he comes back now app open ad is shown then we show a splash screen in between and then go to second activity)

It is not practical to have app open ads and not show banner ads .

Comment: don't implement point one of hiding banner on resume. Create a splash screen and write app open ad code in that activity.